# How to clear record fields from javascript with using Remote action method

Tags: javascript

I have scenario, when user does something on UI (angularjs) and then i have to update some records on backend (salesforce org). The problem is, that if i want to clear some fields of the record, i will not get it on backend.
Lets say we have account with

```
SomeField1__c, value === 'FieldValue1', 
SomeField2__c, value === 'FieldValue2'

account.SomeField1__c = 'SomeNewValue1';
account.SomeField2__c = null;
//callBackend here
```

Then on backend:

```
@RemoteAction
public static String updateAccountRecord(Account acc) {
   update acc; 
   //here i will have
   //acc.SomeField1__c with new value
   //and no SomeField2__c as i changed it to null, no value no field for js :)

   acc = [SELECT Id, SomeField1__c, SomeField2__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id LIMIT 1];

   //here i will have
   acc.SomeField1__c with new value SomeNewValue1
   acc.SomeField2__c with old value FieldValue2

   return 'Success';
}
```

Any elegant solutions here? 
Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending it to the "backend". Me thinks that may be part of the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in my developer edition using the following code:

Apex Code:

```
public class FieldsToNull {
    @RemoteAction public static void updateRecord(Account record) {
        update record;
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="FieldsToNull">
    <script>
        {!$RemoteAction.FieldsToNull.updateRecord}({
              'Id': '001500000154s0C',
              'Name': 'Test Account 1',
              'Industry': null
            },
            function(d,e) {

            }
        );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Since this worked correctly, I can only conclude that you've written something incorrectly in your AngularJS code. RemoteAction methods definitely do work with null field values.

You'll need to check all the usual culprits, like checking your JSON serialization, if any, making sure the field name is case-sensitive with respect to the API name in Salesforce, and so on.

Comment: You are right, i checked the project again and found filter method where we prepare data for backend :)

Comment: But additional question to this, i had few times issues, when i send list of ids (for instance) to backend, i have on backend method which expect string list, but if in my list(array on js) only one element, im getting on backend string, not a list of string. I got this on different projects, so looks like its some problem, how SF parse json on the fly. Do you have any suggestions or ideas about that?